# What's with Garrett glaring at the study group, and then Leonard staring at Garrett?

Tags: plot-explanation, community

In Community S06E01 - "Ladders", there is a scene (at about 24 min, at the end of the actual episode) where Garrett is glaring at the study group, then Leonard staring at Garrett, then Leonard giving a thumbs-up to the camera, while dramatic background music plays. There doesn't seem to be anything about this in episode 2. Is this a reference to a TV show or movie, or is it a reference to a previous event? What's this scene about?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be a reference to a previous event, a movie or TV show, or to introduce a new plot:

> @OkSteev: Was the Garrett/Leonard staring scene a joke or is that a
>   plot for a later day? 
>   @atrubens: Joke. Absurdism.

This is from [Alex Rubens' twitter post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150330113611/https://twitter.com/atrubens/status/578755817068888064). Alex Rubens is one of the writers for Community.

Comment: Too bad, I was hoping for something a little more clever. Good find though, have some rep.

Answer (score 2):

I think it was a joke of Garret wanting a seat at "The" table and Leonard protecting the viewers from that awkward possiblity. clever stuff, basically suggesting the viewers wouldnt really like garret.

Comment: Is this just a theory or do you have anything concrete supporting that interpretation? After watching the scene several times, I am not sure that's really what is going on. It seems more like one of the countless movie references in the show, although I couldn't say what movie/scene is being referenced.

Comment: I half agree with you, MadawaWilson; I think Garret was fuming over a complete newcomer being chosen for the group, rather than an established character, when he looks over and sees Leonard, who is in the same position, but is cool with it.